# Tizen Secured companion samples are not working

Tags: android, signature, tizen

Downloaded the source from here: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/samples/companion/hello-native.html

Also tried here: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/samples/companion/security-native.html

But can not get "secure" socket working between Tizen and Android.

Below some useful logs from Android (as it seems this part is failing):

```
2021-03-23 18:21:37.903 10288-10365/com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.provider D/AccessoryProvider(P): onAuthenticationResponse
2021-03-23 18:21:37.909 10288-10365/com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.provider D/AccessoryProvider(P): onAuthenticationResponse: matched=false, authToken.getKey().length=294, myAppKey.length=162
2021-03-23 18:21:37.910 10288-10365/com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.provider I/[SA_SDK]SAAgentV2: onAuthenticationResponse() -> AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
```

Middle line is mine, the problem is that the `authToken` SAP gives me is not matching with the `myAppKey`. Not maching even by comparing their sizes.

So, if you have any idea on what is `authToken.getKey()`, and what kind of key is it (with length of 294 bytes), let me know please.

`myAppKey` is constructed this way:

```
Signature[] sigs = pkgInfo.signatures;
Log.d(TAG, "getApplicationCertificate, sigs[0].toByteArray().length=" + sigs[0].toByteArray().length); //481

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sigs[0].toByteArray());
X509Certificate x509cert = X509Certificate.getInstance(stream);
myAppKey = x509cert.getPublicKey().getEncoded();
Log.d(TAG, "getApplicationCertificate, x509cert.getPublicKey().getEncoded().length=" + x509cert.getPublicKey().getEncoded().length); //162
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below link to download security sample apps.
https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/samples/companion/security-native.html

And please double check if Author certificate used for building both Tizen & Android apps is same.

Comment: Thanks. This sample doesn't contain any buildable Android project.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to completely reinstall the *Tizen Certificate Manager*.

It was not asking me to choose between *Tizen* or *Samsung* when adding new profile, just directly selected *Tizen* for some weird reason. Therefore I couldn't generate the Author certificate from an imported Android author certificate.

After reinstalled, following the guidance of the SDK, I succeed.